# c# mongodb driver nested bson document

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-6.0

Hello i got an issue with MongoDB model builder like example i have UserModel for adding or updating existing document in mongo
here is one BsonDocument
[one bson document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei8zZ.png)

```
public BsonDocument Premium = new BsonDocument()
                .Add("isPremium", false)
                .Add("PremiumEnds", DateTime.Now)
                .Add("Level", int.Parse("0"))
                .Add("RatioText", double.Parse("1.0"))
                .Add("RatioVoice", double.Parse("1.0"));
```

and if document like this exist in user document like in first screenshot here is an issue
if i add to this BsonDocument new Key/Value like

```
public BsonDocument Premium = new BsonDocument()
                .Add("isPremium", false)
                .Add("PremiumEnds", DateTime.Now)
                .Add("Level", int.Parse("0"))
                .Add("RatioText", double.Parse("1.0"))
                .Add("RatioVoice", double.Parse("1.0"))
                .Add("Key", "Value");`
```

after getting user info and updating some values this will not change the Existing BsonDocument
but if i add to UserModel like

```
public int Prestige { get; set; }
```

outside BsonDocument after updating user new row will appears in document

**Getting User Function**

```
public static async Task<UserMongo> GetUserAsync(ulong id)
{
  var user = Users.Find(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
  if (user != null) return user;
  user = await SignUp(id);
  return user;
}
```

**Updating User Function**

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(UserMongo user)
{
  await Users.ReplaceOneAsync(a => a.Id == user.Id, user);
  return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

What is the problem maybe someone has issue like this?

here is a full screenshot of document
[full document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL516.png)

and full model

```
public class UserMongo
{
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public ulong Id { get; set; }
        public ulong PheonixCoin { get; set; }
        public ulong CSCoin { get; set; }
        public int Prestige { get; set; }
        public ulong XP { get; set; }
        public int Level
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)Math.Sqrt(XP / 115);
            }
        }
        public string QiwiBillID { get; set; }
        public ulong VoiceActive { get; set; }
        public ulong Messages { get; set; }
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument Penalty = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("violations", new BsonArray())
            .Add("warns", new BsonArray())
            .Add("mute", new BsonArray())
            .Add("ban", new BsonArray());
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument Admin = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("isAdmin", false)
            .Add("stats", new BsonDocument()
                .Add("violations", new BsonArray())
                .Add("warns", new BsonArray())
                .Add("mute", new BsonArray())
                .Add("ban", new BsonArray())
                .Add("ticket", new BsonArray()))
            .Add("admin_warns", new BsonArray())
            .Add("admin_at", DateTime.Now)
            .Add("start_at", long.Parse("0"))
            .Add("online_today", long.Parse("0"))
            .Add("online_week", long.Parse("0"))
            .Add("online_month", long.Parse("0"))
            .Add("online_total", long.Parse("0"));
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument Premium = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("isPremium", false)
            .Add("PremiumEnds", DateTime.Now)
            .Add("Level", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("RatioText", double.Parse("1.0"))
            .Add("RatioVoice", double.Parse("1.0"))
            .Add("Key", "Value");
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument Cases = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("Bronze", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Silver", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Gold", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Platinum", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Emerald", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Donate", int.Parse("0"));
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument lfg =  new BsonDocument()
            .Add("SteamID32", uint.Parse("0"))
            .Add("FaceitUrl", "")
            .Add("MMRank", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("WGRank", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("DZRank", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("FCRank", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("PEmoji", int.Parse("0"));
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument personalRole = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("DonateRoleID", long.Parse("0"))
            .Add("RoleEnds", DateTime.Now)
            .Add("AutoRenew", int.Parse("0"));
        
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public BsonDocument profileSettings = new BsonDocument()
            .Add("HideBalance", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("HidePheonix", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("AgentId", int.Parse("1"))
            .Add("BackgroundId", int.Parse("1"))
            .Add("CardId", int.Parse("1"))
            .Add("Icon1", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Icon2", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Icon3", int.Parse("0"))
            .Add("Icon4", int.Parse("0"));
        
        public List<InventoryEntry> Inventory = new List<InventoryEntry>();

        
        public class InventoryEntry
        {
            public int Id;
            public int Category;
            public DateTime EndTime;
            
            public InventoryEntry(int id, int category, DateTime endTime)
            {
                Id = id;
                Category = category;
                EndTime = endTime;
            }
        }
```

also tryed creating BsonDocument in schema like this

```
[BsonIgnoreIfDefault] 
public BsonDocument Premium = new BsonDocument
{
    { "isPremium", false },
    { "PremiumEnds", DateTime.Now },
    { "Level", int.Parse("0") },
    { "RatioText", double.Parse("1.0") },
    { "RatioVoice", double.Parse("1.0") }
};
```

and like this

```
public BsonDocument Prem = new BsonDocument()
    .Add(new BsonElement("isPremium", false))
    .Add(new BsonElement("PremiumEnds", DateTime.Now))
    .Add(new BsonElement("Level", int.Parse("2")))
    .Add(new BsonElement("RatioText", double.Parse("1,3")))
    .Add(new BsonElement("RatioVoice", double.Parse("1,3")));
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if document exist in mongodb and i wanna add new key/value to bsonDocument after updating user by Id its dont add to bsondocument